# Jackson objectmapper adjust timzone to Europe/Amsterdam

Tags: kotlin, jpa, jackson

I'm writing a objectmapper that converts the incomming dates and converts them to my own timezone

```
fun objectMapperCustomizer(): Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer
    {
        return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer { builder ->
            builder.timeZone(TimeZone.getDefault())
            builder.featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            builder.featuresToEnable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
            builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

        }
    }
```

But it's not converting to my localtimezone
Expected :"2022-09-12T13:53:10.864+02:00"

Actual   :"2022-09-12T13:53:10.864Z"

Comment: The first step would be to do a print/log/debug `TimeZone.getDefault()` and check if your environment's time zone is the actual time zone you expect.

Comment: Which data type do you use? Do you use `Java 8` time package?